# Do two MDAs need their own MTAs?

Tags: mail-transport-agent, mail-delivery-agent

Suppose I have an MDA in `example1.com` and an MTA in `example2.com`.
Do I need an extra MTA on `example1.com`?

```
MUA --- MDA  --- MTA --- | Internet | --- MTA --- MDA --- MUA
```

So far I used two MTAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could host both domains on the same setup, so then it would all be local delivery. The MUA->MDA->MTA->MTA->MDA->MUA chain still applies, since it is all involved with mail routing.